# FireStore Rules check if record is being inserted or updated

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I set the following firestore rule on my firebase project

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /news/{news} {
            allow read: if true;
            allow write: if request.auth != null
                         // && (
                               // (resource == null && request.resource.data.author == request.auth.uid) || 
                               // request.auth.uid == resource.data.author == request.resource.data.author || 
                               // get(/users/$(request.auth.uid)).role in ["editor", "admin"]
                            // )
                         && request.resource.data.keys().hasAll(['title', 'body', 'images', 'tags', 'source', 'web_link', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'author'])
                         && request.resource.data.title is string && request.resource.data.title.size() >= 10 && request.resource.data.title.size() <= 100
                         && request.resource.data.body is string && request.resource.data.body.size() >= 300 && request.resource.data.body.size() <= 500
                         && request.resource.data.images is list && request.resource.data.images.size() >= 0
                         && request.resource.data.tags is list && request.resource.data.tags.size() >= 0
                         && request.resource.data.source is string && request.resource.data.source.size() > 0 && request.resource.data.title.size() <= 100
                         && request.resource.data.web_link is string && request.resource.data.web_link.size() > 0
                         // && request.resource.data.created_at is timestamp
                         // && request.resource.data.updated_at is timestamp
                         ;
        }
        match /users/{userId} {
            allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId || get(/users/$(request.auth.uid)).role == "admin"
        }
        match /{document=**} {
            allow read, write: if false;
        }
    }
}
```

The lines commented above don't work

- I need to check if the resource is being inserted or updated, the `resource == null` part doesn't work
- `created_at` and `updated_at` contain timestamp, and `is timestamp` doesn't work

In case anyone is wondering, `resource.data.author` contains `uid` of a user

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#request_methods), writes can be subdivided into:

- create
- update
- delete

So, in this case, you would want something like:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /news/{news} {
      //read rules here...
      allow create: if true; 
      allow update: if true; 
      allow delete: if true; 
    }
  }
  //other rules here...
}
```

There is also [good documentation for validating timestamps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#timestamp). I would strongly advise making use of [firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#.serverTimestamp) where possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same details in the documentation, the following works for me using timestamps and fails if I try send a string (where "lastUpdated" should be swapped with whatever your date property is)

```
request.resource.data.lastUpdated.date() is timestamp
```